# How to check if user click on HTML5 Map area coords

Tags: javascript

I try to check if user click on map area, I need it because I create a find the differences game.
I want to set something like that:
if user click on map area: **alert('yes');**
else if user not click on map area: **alert('no');**

I try to do this (Its for multiple area):

```js
$("#img1").click(function(e){
    if($("map#diffmap").click()) alert('yes');
    else alert('no');
});
```

Thanks for all that try to help, I success to do that

Comment: What is map area exactly ? Is it a rectangle ?

Comment: @rach8garg its a circle, and I talk about multiple areas

Comment: @John What specific js map library are you using. If it is a circle area you should check the API documentation for shape layer events

Comment: @JeremeCausing Sorry but I dont understand about which js library you talking. I talking about this [map area](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

Comment: @John sorry I thought you were talking about maps as in google maps. i forgot about the <map> tag

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet helps.

```js
let outer = document.querySelector('#outer');
let inner = document.querySelector('#inner');
   
let outer_click_handler = function (ev){
  alert("No");
};
   
let inner_click_handler = function (ev){
  alert("Yes");
  ev.stopPropagation();
};
   
outer.addEventListener('click', outer_click_handler);   
inner.addEventListener('click', inner_click_handler);
```

```css
.outer{ 
    background: #123321; 
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.inner{ 
    background: #789987;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div id="outer" class="outer">
  <div id="inner" class="inner">
      MAP
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I need it with the map area tag, [area](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

Comment: You can change the ID in code. replace `inner` with `#diffmap`.

Comment: I dont a proffesional in js and its the first time I see this: `let`, what is it mean?

Comment: same as var with slight difference.

Comment: I have question about your code, I have muliple areas in my map, and for every area have a different id, so how the code can call to every id?

Comment: Learn basics of JavaScript first before popping out fuzzy queries. @John

Comment: What do you talking about? I say that map areas have different id for each one - and in your code you refer to "inner" for the same id, I want in addition do get the clicked area details after click

Comment: First have some courtesy to upvote the answer or comment for effort. I am not a tutor here.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for the rudeness. I was just trying to explain what I meant.